# FullCalendar angular-ui Day numbers cannot be changed to other language

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using Angular-ui fullCalendar, So far I am sucessfully able to use the locale feature of the fullCalendar as angular-ui provides the feature just call a required language js fro the calOptions as shown in code

CODE:

```
  $scope.calOptions = {
          editable: true,
          lang:'hi',
          height: ($(window).height()) - ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 1000)),
          editable : true,
          header : {
          left: 'prev',
          center: 'title,today',
          right: 'next'
          },
```

Now the main issue is that I want to convert the number on the calendar to another language,So far i came to know it is possible by passing the locale js to moment.js which coverts to different language.But this does not changes the number in calendar.

Except calendar date number all the things are converted to the language I needed.By default it always takes english inside the calendar numbers.

To be more clear, can refer to the image.
[image: Language Numbers]

The above image can show the numbers in calendar are in English,I want to covert in to similar language as language outside the Calendar blocks.

I have seen many queries similar to this question but I was failed to achieve.
Any kind of valuable suggestion would be appreciated,Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, these are arabic numerals ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: Q: are you using/including `lang-all.js`?

Comment: No I am not using lang-all.js